# Firefox fails to start in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, firefox, snap

I tried to start Firefox in ubuntu via 'firefox' command in terminal, but nothing happens, and I got this message :

> Content snap command-chain for /snap/firefox/2748/gnome-platform/command-chain/desktop- launch not found: ensure slot is connected

I removed the firefox:

> sudo snap remove firefox

and I re-installed it :

> sudo snap install firefox

during the installation I got this message :

> 2023-06-08T18:06:04+02:00 INFO failed to update "gnome-42-2204", will not have required content
> "gnome-42-2204": snap has no updates available
> firefox 114.0-3 par Mozilla✓ installed

someone could highlight me about the issue and why it cannot launch ?

Thanks

Comment: You can switch to the APT version of Firefox https://askubuntu.com/q/1399383/124466